# installing miniconda in WSL UBUNTU

Tags: installation, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I executed:

```
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.7.12.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda2-4.7.12.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and received the following error code

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while
>   installing package 'defaults::python-2.7.17-h9bab390_0'.

I thought it would make sense to delete what had been installed and try again with

```
$rm -rf /home/username/miniconda2/
```

then received the following error:

> rm: cannot remove
>   '/home/username/miniconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.17-h9bab390_0/bin/python2.7':
>   Permission denied

I'm not sure what to do next. Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wn10 detects python2.7 binary as a threat and quarantines it, so it's not working.

See issue opened for conda:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9561

and associated submission to Microsoft:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/submission/b139ccc5-79c0-490f-a963-495e2cce78da

Fix: 
1. Download python 2.7 package from https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?sort=distribution_type&sort_order=desc&version=2.7.17

2. Manually unpack it, allow Windows 10 to detect threat.
3. Go to virus protection history in Windows and allow that file. From now on Windows won't automatically quarantine it.
4. Re-deploy Conda or Python 2.7 environment.

Comment: Microsoft acknowledged the issue and removed false detection: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/submission/1e776254-ccc1-409a-a18f-5b7a54a9c943